# Removing enumerators in a line of data

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a Data file (.txt) constructed in the following manner:

```
AmountItem ItemName
AmountItem ItemName
...
```

The `ItemName` may contain all characters including whitespaces and special characters.
The `AmountItem` is an integer.

What I am trying to do is to get a `List<String>` containing unique entries of `ItemName`s where each `ItemName` of the data file is present once.

I tried to accomplish this by reading out the file with a BufferedReader `reader` filtering each line for the `ItemName` in the following way

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
reader = new BufferedReader(...);

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    boolean noElement = true;

    line = line.replace("\\d+ ",""); \\remove the amount

    for(String str : test)
        if(str.equals(line))
            noElement = false;

     if(noElement)
        test.add(line); 
}
```

All is working fine, except the amount of each Item is not removed.

I tried removing something from test strings like `"12341 foo".replace("\\d","X")` which returns `12341 foo` as the replaced String. Same goes for other regex wildcards and control characters e.g. `"12341 foo".replace("^1","X")` returning `"12341 foo"`. However replacing a single character in the string works.

What did I do wrong? Or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a more efficient way to do this, but to be able to use regex for the replace, you need to use `.replaceAll`. That said, you will also have to change your regex a little so that it doesn't remove too much characters:

```
line = line.replaceAll("^\\d+ ","");
```

`^` matches the beginning of the line, so that only the first numbers (and space) are removed.

Comment: More efficient way could perhaps be split on space, remove the first element in the result array and then join them back on space.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would just use a simple [`String.split(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a `limit` of `2`:

```
String[] parts = line.split(" ", 2);
String amount = parts[0];
String name = parts[1];
```

Comment: right. in this case String.split(" ",2) is ~20µs faster than string.replaceAll("^\\d+ ","")